# MYSQL using multiple CASE REGEXP for each letter as table row, and also allow repeated/duplicate calculations for each of the said REGEXPied letter

Tags: mysql, regex, case

Say I have the following simple table in MYSQL (table name: test)

```
id  letter
1   A
2   BC
3   AB
4   C
5   AC
6   BA
7   CAB
8   C
```

My objective is to create another table with the letters becomes rows of a column and another column to count the number of the letters. Here is my MYSQL query:

```
SELECT
    (CASE   WHEN letter REGEXP 'A' THEN 'A'
            WHEN letter REGEXP 'B' THEN 'B'
            WHEN letter REGEXP 'C' THEN 'C'
     END) LETTER,
    COUNT(letter) COUNT_OF_LETTER
FROM test
GROUP BY (CASE  WHEN letter REGEXP 'A' THEN 'A'
                WHEN letter REGEXP 'B' THEN 'B'
                WHEN letter REGEXP 'C' THEN 'C'
          END);
```

The output of the query is:

```
LETTER  COUNT_OF_LETTER
A       5
B       1
C       2
```

While the count for A is correct, B and C are not. For entries in the table 'test' that have multiple letters, once it has been counted as A, it will not be counted again for B and/or C. The same goes to B - the C are skipped if it has been counted for B. My expected output should be like this:

```
LETTER  COUNT_OF_LETTER
A       5
B       4
C       5
```

If I,say,create just a single CASE WHEN only for each individual letter, it correctly count A as 5, B as 4 and C as 5, but not when using multiple WHEN like above.

I've searched around SO for anything similar but it does not solve this kind of problem. Anyway, thanks for helping me on this.

Regards,
Shahiran.

Comment: Well this is how CASE … WHEN is _supposed_ to work - it stops as soon as it finds the first matching case.

Comment: Don't reuse names; it is confusing and possibly does not do what you expect.  I am referring to the column `LETTER` and the alias `letter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
create table tbl(id int, letters varchar(5));
insert into tbl values
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'BC'),
(3, 'AB'),
(4, 'C'),
(5, 'AC'),
(6, 'BA'),
(7, 'CAB'),
(8, 'C');
```

Try this:

```
select 'A' letter, sum(length(letters) - length(replace(letters, 'A', ''))) occurences from tbl
union all
select 'B', sum(length(letters) - length(replace(letters, 'B', ''))) from tbl
union all
select 'C', sum(length(letters) - length(replace(letters, 'C', ''))) from tbl
```

But I prefer this way:

```
select sum(length(letters) - length(replace(letters, 'A', ''))) A,
       sum(length(letters) - length(replace(letters, 'B', ''))) B,
       sum(length(letters) - length(replace(letters, 'C', ''))) C
from tbl
```

Comment: Turczyn...thanks! Initially I was thinking of keep using the CASE WHEN style and try to figure how to work around it, since I need to use REGEXP to get that single letter from a string. Your way is indeed ingenious, I never thought of using LENGTH and REPLACE at all..Thanks again!